Average of ratios - out of all possible combinations
I have a very dummy question :)
I have two variables, $X$ and $Y$, observed independently. I want to know the estimate of ratio, $Z=X/Y$, using average of ratios.
Can I calculate all possible combinations of $x_1/y_1$, $x_1/y_2$, ... , $x_1/y_m$, ... $x_n/y_m$ and take average of such sample, so $$\bar{r}=\frac{1}{n\cdot m}\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{m}\frac{x_i}{y_j} \ ?$$ It seems for me that this is kind of bootstrapping, but I can't grasp the potential error here. Having $X$ and $Y$ of different lengths and not very long, I hope this approach will give a better estimate.

I don't think this is "dummy", actually it's interesting whether and how one could do better than what you propose here (which as a first shot surely makes some sense). In any case, regarding notation, $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ would usually be the true quantity you want to estimate (as far as I understand your posting), i.e., the true unobserved expected value of $Z$. What you call  $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ is an estimator computed on data, which would normally be denoted with a lower case letter (such as $\bar r$), or upper case ($\bar R$, say) if you mean the random variable. But then based on $X_i, Y_j$...

Should we take for granted that you don't want to make any parametric model assumptions for $X, Y$? With such assumptions one can probably do better; without it is much more difficult. (It's not "kind of bootstrapping" by the way.)

We need more context on these ratios. Can we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are always positive? If not, what exceptions occur? Can you show the distribution of ratios? My brief reaction is that I would average ratios only reluctantly, but I might wonder whether the geometric mean of ratios makes sense AND (quite separately) whether a pooled estimate $\sum{X} / \sum{Y}$ makes sense.

@ChristianHennig yes, you're right, I meant the estimator obviously :)
$X$ and $Y$ are always positive, may be approximated with normal distribution, but are not from normal distribution in general.

Closing this seems harsh just because a few clarifications could help. I've seen much less clear questions that haven't been closed.

Indeed, but the point of closing here is to get clarifications and to cut down on speculation and on suggestions that may turn out to be inapplicable. For example, I suggested geometric means, but that might be out of order.  @ChristianHennig

Re "different lengths:" it sounds like you are looking for an estimate of the ratio of expectations, $E[X]/E[Y].$  This is not the expectation of the ratio, $E[X/Y].$  Moreover, you have no basis to estimate the latter because you don't have paired data and therefore have no information about the relationship between $X$ and $Y,$ which is crucial for determining $Z.$
